# How to plot individual rows as line plots in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

My current df

```
       mean_1   mean_2       mean_3      mean_4  Average Percent Change
index                   

Q33 3.800000    3.800000    3.898305    4.067797    7.05
Q35 3.266667    3.333333    3.491525    3.864407    15.93
Q37 2.516667    3.200000    3.338983    3.593220    12.29
Q39 2.833333    3.366667    3.661017    3.932203    16.80
Q41 2.933333    3.516667    3.610169    4.067797    15.67
Q43 2.700000    3.416667    3.677966    4.033898    18.07
Q45 2.700000    3.233333    6.593220    6.966102    115.45
Q47 2.766667    3.316667    6.610169    6.881356    107.48
Q52 4.000000    4.083333    7.322034    7.423729    81.81
Q54 4.216667    4.900000    8.067797    8.169492    66.72
```

I want to iterate through every single row and plot a line chart for every single row. The means 1-4 being individual points on the line graph and the percentage change located clearly on some area within the graph towards the right side.  Preferably all in a subplot but its not a big deal if its not. I rather set the titles individually but if thats not possible I have a table i marge to. X-axis will be the means 1-4 and the Y-axis will have the actual mean measurements.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit], and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort.